# I mistakenly deleted the HD Data Partition in my 2019 iMac 2TB Fusion drive when trying to downgrade OS back to Mojave. Need help to get it back

Tags: macos, partition, fusion-drive

I backed up whole drive with CCC first, but booting from that does not seem to finish loading. Starting up from a USB Mojave installer (which I have used before) I reformatted to HFS extended and then back to APFS. I did not use the convert function to go back to APFS. Then I used the USB Mojave Installer successfully but it only shows Macintosh HD at the top level but not a Container with HD and HD-Data volumes. Apple Store person said I could use Mojave or Catalina installer, which I also have, to erase either the container or the whole drive. But I am reluctant to experiment further without more confirming advice.

Comment: Can you add to your question the results (in text mode) of the terminal command : `diskutil list internal`?

Comment: I can do that when i am at work tomorrow.

Comment: -bash: disk: command not found

Comment: Try the terminal command   `diskutil list`

Answer (score 0):

Correct.  Mojave does not create a container with multiple volumes.  Mojave has a container with a single volume.  Everything is as it should be.  Boot your USB installer, create a single HFS volume, install Mojave.  Allow it to migrate to APFS as a part of installing the OS.  Now, restore your data.

Comment: That will be easy to do. But why do my other iMac, and my Macbook pro, both running Mojave, have both HD and HD-Data volumes?

Comment: Because you created them or left them there by installing Catalina or later and downgrading.  See https://eclecticlight.co/2019/08/29/macos-mojave-boot-volume-layout/